# Describe each set by extension $P(P(\emptyset))$ and $P(P(\{\emptyset\})$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

where $P$ represents the power set and $\emptyset$ the empty set

I think is $\emptyset$ but I am not sure

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: thank you ......

Comment: This is definitely not a question about number theory. And if you're going to use the tag "solution-verification" you should actually write a solution.

Comment: I am sorry sir thats right I dont know how to start the solution

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$P(P(\emptyset))= P(\{\emptyset\})= \{\emptyset,\{ \emptyset \}\}$. This is a set of two elements. The second set $P(P(\{\emptyset\})) = P(\{\emptyset,\{ \emptyset \}\})$ is the power set of the previous set, which is a set of four elements.

Comment: brilliant solution

Comment: $P(\{\emptyset\}) = \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}$.

Comment: I just Fixed it.

Comment: @温泽海  the four elemnts would be {∅,{∅}{∅,{∅}}?

Comment: I just count only three ...

Comment: what about {{∅,{∅},{∅},{∅,{∅}}}

Comment: @samuelcrhis It's not a guessing game. And {{∅,{∅},{∅},{∅,{∅}}} has an unmatched "{".